# WPF Need help about panels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, panel

I uploaded my window picture, there in white space i need to fill with user controls but i cannot anchor it top, bottom, left, right please advice how i can do that thanks :)

XAML

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="H_Pro.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    Title="H-Pro. Version 1.0.0" Height="394" Width="856" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="RibbonWindow_Loaded">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <my:Ribbon x:Name="MainRibbon" Height="auto" Width="auto" AllowDrop="False" ClipToBounds="False" DataContext="{Binding}" Focusable="True" IsCollapsed="False" IsDropDownOpen="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" IsMinimized="False">
                <my:RibbonTab  Header="Main">
                    <my:RibbonGroup Name="SecurityRibbonGroup" Header="Security" Width="100">
                        <my:RibbonButton Name="btnChangeUser" Label="Change User" LargeImageSource="/H-Pro;component/Images/1310403730_group.png" Click="btnChangeUser_Click">

                        </my:RibbonButton>
                        <my:RibbonButton Name="btnUserList" Label="Users List" LargeImageSource="/H-Pro;component/Images/1294319913_people.png" Click="btnUserList_Click" />
                    </my:RibbonGroup>
                    <my:RibbonGroup Name="BookingOperationsRibbonGroup" Header="Booking Informations" Width="auto">
                        <my:RibbonButton Label="New Booking" Name="btnNewBooking" LargeImageSource="/H-Pro;component/Images/1310421580_appointment-new.png" />
                        <my:RibbonButton Label="Booking List" Name="btnBookingList" LargeImageSource="/H-Pro;component/Images/booking.png"/>
                    </my:RibbonGroup>
                    <my:RibbonGroup Name="GuestRibbonGroup" Header="Guest Operations" Width="auto">
                        <my:RibbonButton Name="btnGuestDataBase" Label="Guest Database" LargeImageSource="/H-Pro;component/Images/dbd.png" />
                        <my:RibbonGroup />
                        <my:RibbonButton Label="Add New Guest"/>
                        <my:RibbonButton Label="Top Guests"/>
                    </my:RibbonGroup>
                </my:RibbonTab>
                <my:RibbonTab Header="Add/Edit" Name="AddEditRibbonTab">
                    <my:RibbonGroup Name="AddRooms" Header="Rooms" Width="auto">
                        <my:RibbonButton Label="Add/Edit Rooms" Name="btnAddEditRooms" LargeImageSource="/H-Pro;component/Images/1310459678_hotel4stars.png" />
                    </my:RibbonGroup>
                </my:RibbonTab>
            </my:Ribbon>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Yellow"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="White" Height="23">
                <StatusBar Height="23" Name="MainStatusBar" Width="auto" />
                </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="AliceBlue" Width="49" Height="auto"/>

        </DockPanel> 

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details? Cannot anchor it meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion: Add another row to your Grid and move your StatusBar to the grid instead of the DockPanel.

And with something like StackPanel, if you set the Height/Width to Auto, or don't specify the Height/Width, it won't fill the parent control by default. Auto will use up as much space as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Place your UserControl within the content area and set it to 'stretch':

```
<local:MyUserControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

This will ensure it fills the content area.

Comment: I have lots of user controls i must wright this code for all of them?